# A problem while deplying laravel application to AWS Elastic beans

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, web-deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a laravel application to AWS Elastic beanstalk, I'm supposed to upload a zip file contains my source code, and I'm getting this error below:

```
 /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
    a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
    latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
    the last disk(s) of this archive.
```

Log

```
[2019-08-24T13:43:37.154Z] INFO  [3147]  - [Application deployment siitag-laravel-source-1@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2019-08-24T13:43:37.154Z] INFO  [3147]  - [Application deployment siitag-laravel-source-1@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.sh] : Starting activity...
[2019-08-24T13:43:37.454Z] INFO  [3147]  - [Application deployment siitag-laravel-source-1@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k source_bundle
  + EB_SOURCE_BUNDLE=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  + rm -rf /var/app/ondeck
  + /usr/bin/unzip -d /var/app/ondeck /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
    a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
    latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
    the last disk(s) of this archive.
  unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle or
          /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle.zip, and cannot find /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle.ZIP, period. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k source_bundle
  + EB_SOURCE_BUNDLE=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  + rm -rf /var/app/ondeck
  + /usr/bin/unzip -d /var/app/ondeck /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
    End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
    a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
    latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
    the last disk(s) of this archive.
  unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle or
          /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle.zip, and cannot find /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle.ZIP, period. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)


[2019-08-24T13:43:37.454Z] INFO  [3147]  - [Application deployment siitag-laravel-source-1@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.sh] : Activity failed.
[2019-08-24T13:43:37.454Z] INFO  [3147]  - [Application deployment siitag-laravel-source-1@1/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Activity failed.
```

I have no idea how to solve this, and any thoughts or solutions are appreciated

Comment: just to remove the obvious culprit, your source code *is* only in a single zip file, right? If so, have you tried a different zip utility, or uploading the source code to s3?

Comment: how are you zipping your source code?

Comment: I'm on windows and I'm using winRAR, the generated file is .rar

Comment: and I'm zipping all the files under the root directory.

Comment: WinRar does multipart zips... Make sure its not a multipart zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to just compress the source code to be `.zip` instead of `.rar`